# Raise a table of pre-existing data to the power of of one of the variables

Tags: list-manipulation, arithmetic

**NOTE**: I have edited this question to give a table whose first elements don't count up from `0` to `5`.

I'm using a sample table here, given by `Table[a/b + a^(1/2), {b, 1, 6}, {a, 1, 6}]` - simply because it's small and easy. This gives me the following data:

```
testtable1 = {{2, 2 + Sqrt[2], 3 + Sqrt[3], 6, 5 + Sqrt[5], 
6 + Sqrt[6]}, {3/2, 1 + Sqrt[2], 3/2 + Sqrt[3], 4, 5/2 + Sqrt[5], 
3 + Sqrt[6]}, {4/3, 2/3 + Sqrt[2], 1 + Sqrt[3], 10/3, 
5/3 + Sqrt[5], 2 + Sqrt[6]}, {5/4, 1/2 + Sqrt[2], 3/4 + Sqrt[3], 3,
5/4 + Sqrt[5], 3/2 + Sqrt[6]}, {6/5, 2/5 + Sqrt[2], 3/5 + Sqrt[3],
14/5, 1 + Sqrt[5], 6/5 + Sqrt[6]}, {7/6, 1/3 + Sqrt[2], 
1/2 + Sqrt[3], 8/3, 5/6 + Sqrt[5], 1 + Sqrt[6]}}
```

But now I want to raise that table to the power of `b` - **without** going back to create a new table. Of course, it's easy to say `Table[(a/b + a^(1/2))^b, {b, 1, 6}, {a, 1, 6}]` - but that's only because this is a simple table. I'm looking for an operation that I can apply generically to **any** `testtable1`, because the calculations involved in getting to my actual `testtable1` are very big and very slow, and hit the error limits of Mathematica - i.e., they become inaccurate. So, I want to crunch the data I have already generated rather than modify the original calculation.

Is this possible? Maybe I need to turn `testtable1` into a dataset? Pointers on how to tackle this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you prefer exact computations or is it okay to use (inexact) floating point numbers? The latter would speed up your calculations tremendously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you generate you table equivalently by

```
alist = Range[1, 6];
blist = Range[1, 6];
testtable1 = Table[a/b + a^(1/2), {b, blist}, {a, alist}];
```

Then

```
Table[(a/b + a^(1/2))^b, {b, blist}, {a, alist}]
```

can be obtained also by

```
testtable1^blist
```

and

```
Table[(a/b + a^(1/2))^a, {b, blist}, {a, alist}]
```

can be obtained by

```
testtable1^ConstantArray[alist, Length[blist]]
```

The key observation is that `^` (a.k.a. `Power`) has the attribute `Listable`.

For a preexisting table

```
testtable2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 2000}];
```

the following should raise each row to the power of its row count:

```
poweredbyrow = testtable2^Range[1, Length[testtable2]];
```

The same for powering by column number:

```
poweredbycol = 
  testtable2^ConstantArray[
    Range[1, Dimensions[testtable2][[2]]], 
    Length[testtable2]
    ];
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this solution essentially relies on the fact that the first item in each entry in the table counts up from `0` to `5` - in which case, I gave a poor example, because that's not necessarily the case... I'll edit the original post.

Comment: Well, if you generate your table by `a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000}];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2000}];
testtable1 = Outer[Plus, b, a];`, then you can use `testtable1^b;`. Btw.: Using the list `a` as powers can be done as follows: `testtable1^ConstantArray[a, Length[b]];`

Comment: Hi Henrik (again!). Thanks for helping. This is really useful, but again it's dependent on the specific nature of the table. My situation is that I have a very big pre-existing array/table of data, defined only by its name. I want to raise each row to the power of the number of that row. Row 5, raise to the power of 5; row 2, raise to the power of 2...

Comment: Dear Richard, always at your service ;) I exanded my answer. Does it help you?

Comment: Thanks again, Henrik. It's going to take me a bit of time to wade through that. I'm sure it's exactly right, but I need to go all the way back to my original calculations, and figure out each step of your cunning plan :-). I'll mark as answered after that, but would you mind checking back in, say, half an hour just to see if I have any further questions? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. Just leave a comment under my post or bing me with @+my name in any other comment; I will be notified.

Comment: Hi again. This works close to perfectly - Thank you. But I have one extra query. At an earlier stage in generating `testtable1`, I replaced `ComplexInfinity` with `"-"`, by adding `/. ComplexInfinity -> "-"`. Now, at those locations in the table, `poweredbyrow` gives me expressions like `-^3`. Not sure how to replace them because the powers change, and I don't know how to substitute the text string back to `"-".

Comment: Apply `ReplaceAll` with the rule `Power["-",p_]->"-"` to the output. This will turn all expressions of the form `"-"^p` back to `"-"`.

Comment: OK, Henrik, klgr. Marking both your answers. Very much appreciated as always.

Comment: You're welcome as always.

Answer (score 3):

#### row $k$ raised to the power $k$:

```
MapIndexed[#^#2[[1]] &, testtable1, {1}] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  2 & 2+\sqrt{2} & 3+\sqrt{3} & 6 & 5+\sqrt{5} & 6+\sqrt{6} \\
>  \frac{9}{4} & \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt{3}\right)^2 & 16 & \left(\frac{5}{2}+\sqrt{5}\right)^2 &
>    \left(3+\sqrt{6}\right)^2 \\
>  \frac{64}{27} & \left(\frac{2}{3}+\sqrt{2}\right)^3 & \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)^3 & \frac{1000}{27} &
>    \left(\frac{5}{3}+\sqrt{5}\right)^3 & \left(2+\sqrt{6}\right)^3 \\
>  \frac{625}{256} & \left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2}\right)^4 & \left(\frac{3}{4}+\sqrt{3}\right)^4 & 81 &
>    \left(\frac{5}{4}+\sqrt{5}\right)^4 & \left(\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt{6}\right)^4 \\
>  \frac{7776}{3125} & \left(\frac{2}{5}+\sqrt{2}\right)^5 & \left(\frac{3}{5}+\sqrt{3}\right)^5 & \frac{537824}{3125} &
>    \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^5 & \left(\frac{6}{5}+\sqrt{6}\right)^5 \\
>  \frac{117649}{46656} & \left(\frac{1}{3}+\sqrt{2}\right)^6 & \left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{3}\right)^6 & \frac{262144}{729} &
>    \left(\frac{5}{6}+\sqrt{5}\right)^6 & \left(1+\sqrt{6}\right)^6 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

#### column $k$ raised to the power $k$:

```
MapIndexed[#^#2[[2]] &, testtable1, {2}] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  2 & \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)^2 & \left(3+\sqrt{3}\right)^3 & 1296 & \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)^5 & \left(6+\sqrt{6}\right)^6
>    \\
>  \frac{3}{2} & \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt{3}\right)^3 & 256 & \left(\frac{5}{2}+\sqrt{5}\right)^5
>    & \left(3+\sqrt{6}\right)^6 \\
>  \frac{4}{3} & \left(\frac{2}{3}+\sqrt{2}\right)^2 & \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)^3 & \frac{10000}{81} &
>    \left(\frac{5}{3}+\sqrt{5}\right)^5 & \left(2+\sqrt{6}\right)^6 \\
>  \frac{5}{4} & \left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{3}{4}+\sqrt{3}\right)^3 & 81 &
>    \left(\frac{5}{4}+\sqrt{5}\right)^5 & \left(\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt{6}\right)^6 \\
>  \frac{6}{5} & \left(\frac{2}{5}+\sqrt{2}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{3}{5}+\sqrt{3}\right)^3 & \frac{38416}{625} &
>    \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^5 & \left(\frac{6}{5}+\sqrt{6}\right)^6 \\
>  \frac{7}{6} & \left(\frac{1}{3}+\sqrt{2}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{3}\right)^3 & \frac{4096}{81} &
>    \left(\frac{5}{6}+\sqrt{5}\right)^5 & \left(1+\sqrt{6}\right)^6 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) $

Also:

```
Transpose @ MapIndexed[#^#2[[1]] &, Transpose @ testtable1, {1}]
```

> same result